# Unable to convert coordinate format

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am trying to figure out the format of the coordinate pair below.

My task is to convert a list of these integer values into decimal degrees (below), but this is my only ground truth data point.  Does anyone have an idea of what format (it doesn't seem to be degrees minutes seconds) the above pair could be in?   The conversion should result in the decimal degrees coord pair below

*?DDM?*

```
  "current_position": {
    "latitude": 51329338,
    "longitude": -77573
  }
```

*Decimal degrees coordinates*

```
  "current_position": {
    "latitude": 51.548896666666664,
    "longitude": -0.12928833333333334
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be degrees and decimal minutes:

51329338= 51 degrees, 32.9338 minutes

Then in decimal degrees latitude:

```
51 + 32.9338/60.0 =51.54889666666666
```

and longitude:

```
-7.7573/60.0=-0.129288333333333
```